# How to make a layout in React Router v4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I've done a lot of googling but cannot solve the issue I have...

I am building a social network profile page with different sections on it. I want the core profile information to always be visible, but clicking certain links like 'photos' to change other components.

Here is my code:

App.js (routes)

```
class App extends React.Component {
  [ ... ]

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>

          <Navigation {...props} />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/u/:id" component={Profile} />
            <Route component={NotFound} />
          </Switch>
          <Footer />
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

Profile Component (changes what is rendered based on user account type):

```
const renderProfile = (user, id, type) => {
  if (type === 'artist') {
    return <Route render={() => <ArtistProfilePage id={id} />} />;
  } else {
    [ ... ]
  }
};

const Profile = ({ loading, user, id, type }) => (<div>
  { !loading && renderProfile(user, id, type) }
</div>);
```

ArtistProfilePage (this is the page I want to always display certain components but load different ones if the URL changes:

```
class ArtistProfilePageNew extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="ArtistProfilePage">
        <ArtistInfo />

        <Link to="/">Artist Media</Link>

        <Link to="lineup">Line-up</Link>

        <Link to="gigs">Gigs</Link>

        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" render={() => <ArtistMedia />} /> // this works
          <Route path="/lineup" render={() => <ArtistLineup />} /> // this doesn't
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is that when the url is `u/:id` and the user type is 'artist', the `ArtistProfilePage` component is displayed. This is working

By default I want the ArtistProfilePage to render the `<ArtistMedia />` component which is also working

My issue is that when a user clicks the link for `lineup` so the URL becomes `u/:id/lineup`, the app shows the 404 page as opposed to rendering the `<ArtistLineup />` component under `<ArtistInfo />` and the links.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you are creating route /lineup inside `ArtistProfilePageNew` you need to append the previous URL before it. So your component will become:

```
class ArtistProfilePageNew extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const { match } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="ArtistProfilePage">
        <ArtistInfo />

        <Link to={`${match.url}/`}>Artist Media</Link>

        <Link to={`${match.url}/lineup`}>Line-up</Link>

        <Link to={`${match.url}/gigs`}>Gigs</Link>

        <Switch>
          <Route path={`${match.url}/`} component={ArtistMedia} />
          <Route path={`${match.url}/lineup`} component={ArtistLineup} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Also I would change your Profile component to this:

```
const renderProfile = (user, id, type, match) => {
  if (type === 'artist') {
    return <ArtistProfilePage id={id} match={match} />;
  } else {
    [ ... ]
  }
};

const Profile = ({ loading, user, id, type, match }) => (<div>
  { !loading && renderProfile(user, id, type, match) }
</div>);
```

Since the Profile component is rendered via Route, it should automatically get the match param injected. If no, then you need to wrap your ArtistProfilePageNew with the `withRouter` from `react-router` package.

My solution is not tested, but it should give you an idea about what is wrong.

Hope it helps!

**EDIT:**
You need to remove the **exact** argument from your parent route, so your App will become:

```
class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>

          <Navigation {...props} />
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/u/:id" component={Profile} />
            <Route component={NotFound} />
          </Switch>
          <Footer />
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

Wokring example on CodePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eeMMBd

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply - appreciate it!

Unfortunately I still have the same issue. The `/` route is working perfectly, it renders `<ArtistMedia />` but the `lineup` and `gigs` routes throw a 404. I can't work out why

Comment: Just one mistake, forgot to add match param to renderProfile function, so this should be correct:  `const renderProfile = (user, id, type,match) => {`

Comment: I added that but still no luck!

Comment: Ha! Now I see it, just remove the exact from your /u/:id route and you will be fine ;) When the router sees anything else than **exact** /u/:id it will fall to NotFound route. I have created working example on CodePen for you: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eeMMBd

Comment: It's working! Thank you so much for taking the time to help me - I *really* appreciate it!